# Using anchors in python regex to get exact match

Tags: python, regex

I need to validate a version number consisting of 'v' plus positive int, and nothing else
eg "v4", "v1004"

I have

```
import re
pattern = "\Av(?=\d+)\W"

m = re.match(pattern, "v303")
if m is None:
    print "noMatch"
else:
    print "match"
```

But this doesn't work! Removing the \A and \W will match for v303 but will also match for v30G, for example

Thanks

Answer (score 25):

Pretty straightforward. First, put anchors on your pattern:

```
"^patternhere$"
```

Now, let's put together the pattern:

```
"^v\d+$"
```

That should do it.

Answer (score 6):

I think you may want `\b` (word boundary) rather than `\A` (start of string) and `\W` (non word character), also you don't need to use lookahead (the `(?=...)`).

Try: `"\bv(\d+)"` if you need to capture the int, `"\bv\d+"` if you don't.

**Edit**: You probably want to use raw string syntax for Python regexes, `r"\bv\d+\b"`, since `"\b"` is a backspace character in a regular string.

**Edit 2**: Since `+` is "greedy", no trailing `\b` is necessary or desired.

Answer (score 3):

Simply use

```
 \bv\d+\b
```

Or enclosed it with `^\bv\d+\b$`

to match it entirely..