# how to solve actions on google-Api.ai error

Tags: actions-on-google

[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5c2hU.jpg)[The one screen shot of this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HzsDx.jpg)issue I am building an app using api.ai , an syllabus app which tells you the syllabus, but when I invoke it with desired parameters like branch and semester I have made each individual intent for it even then I'm getting miss answers sometimes like when asked for sem 4 and branch electronics its showing sem 3 sem 4 or of other branch . I have given sem and branch as required n given few invoking statements even then getting this. Tried even training it manually for free 30s of actions on api.ai no solution please help. Not using any web hook , context , event.

Comment: Hi Prithviraj, Could you please add some screenshots, it would be very helpful here to understand what you trying to do.

Comment: Agree. If you can include some screen shots of the intents, and examples of what you're saying and what is failing, it would go a long way to figuring out what is going on.

Comment: screenshots:- 1) https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/x69dXer9sRfJs4rnmWZRtEINV4ySbnfvExEdMbVnfPlEzlGmoY8Qoih5EPsEEPUP6AHqPWcKvgOj3oQ=w1600-h745-rw  2) https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/1CUzqxysvJ6qjT5EvHcYEu8MF7wQ-KiraDlxFFRNmOLYHArboIJSTgmcUPM8yoBY-VwJ43C4BlFUaw8=w1600-h745-rw  3) https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/pfpOJFBQXheM_ZNKBeBcx4YPZi6HX0c7X5oDU2NXMMs5irOI_6QhhHKAAGfNJxosvo9kErb2Hnznn48=w1600-h745-rw

Comment: Request your attention on it.

Comment: Yeah have done it please check it out

Comment: Link to screenshots are giving 503 error. if you can edit your question with screenshot, that would be great :)

Comment: Sukh i have updated the screen shots please review and oblige me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An simple trick would be what i did, just have an entity saved for both branch and semester , use sys.original parameters and an common phrase for provoking each intent saves up the hard work.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer - check here for screenshots [http://imgur.com/a/tVBlD](https://imgur.com/a/tVBlD)

Long answer - You have two options

1) Create 3 separate custom entities for each branch type (computer science, civil, communication) which you need to attach to your branch parameter

2) Using the sys.any entity and attaching it to your branch parameter; then determining what the incoming parameter value is on a server then sending back a response through a webhook.

If you go the second route, you have to create a webhook and hardcode recognized words like 'computer science' in IF statements which check the incoming parameter (sent through JSON from API.AI). This route will be more difficult but I think you will have to travel it regardless because you will have backend architecture which you access to find and return the syllabus.

Note the second route is what I did to solve a similar issue.

You can also use regex to match an item in a list which limits the amount of hardcoding and if statements you have to do.

Python regex search example

```
        baseurl = "http://mywebsite.com:9001/"  
        # Parse the document 
        # Build the URL + File Path and Parse the Document    
        url = baseurl + 'Data'
        xmlLink = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
        xmlData = etree.parse(xmlLink)
        xmlLink.close()    

        # Find the number of elements to cycle through 
        numberOfElements = xmlData.xpath("count(//myData/data)")
        numberOfElements = int(numberOfElements)
        types = xmlData.xpath("//myData/data")


        # Search the string        
        i = 0
        while numberOfElements > i:
            listSearch= types[i].text

            match = re.search(parameter, listSearch, re.IGNORECASE)

            if match is None:
                i += 1
            else:
                # Grab the ID 
                elementID = types[i].get('id')
                i = 0
                break
```

Comment: Yeah ! I was aware of it even tried the 1) step as my action requires both branch & semester tried making each a separate entity even then faced the same error. Now with same model I'm able to get results you can say 7/10 times you get accurate results.. but worried about the 3 other.  And I was aware of using the web hook as you mentioned in 2nd step but hard coding would take me almost few hundred of if statements . But even there  I want the user to get me the exact semester as well as branch to provide an response. And I got conflicting scenarios where semesters and branches cross match.

Comment: Have you tried using regex? You might be able to do something that route where you try to match the incoming parameter to anything in a list you have. I have added an example to my answer about using regex in python; it might be what you're looking for. 

I used a similar solution with a much shorter list (it was maybe 20-30 music genres) but (!) had done that explicitly so the person could say 'Play party music' or 'Play dance music' since the genre was classified as both 'Dance/Party'. Also, I'm actually new to Python for this specific job, it's not hard to pick up and a great language.

Comment: Updated my answer. You can make regex (regular expressions) find an exact match. My example of regex which I just added to the answer doesn't show this but it is easy enough. [Here is another question which has an exact match example.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7879600/using-anchors-in-python-regex-to-get-exact-match)

It definitely cuts down on the hardcoding. And one other thing; you could use sys.any as the parameter for that route it is what I did.